# Protection from reflection - android

Tags: android, reflection

Even a private member/function of my class can be accessed by reflection by using `setAccessible(true)`. Is there a way to prevent this kind of access from outside code?

I read something, here on stack-overflow, that I can use `SecurityManager` for prevention of reflection in applets(not sure how it works, though), but is there a similar mechanism for Android as well? Maybe an annotation or clever-programming?

Comment: What "outside code" are you worried about?

Comment: any code not in my class, making use of my private functions. It may be part of my app, even the same package, but by using reflection, it runs the risk of using the private code in a manner its not supposed to be used.

Comment: Before you try to build a defense, consider they could also just root android and then read your program memory.

Answer (score 14):

Taking a step back, what you're observing is a difference in security philosophy, between the Java execution model as originally embodied in JVMs at Sun and the execution model of Android.

The original Java VM design was intended for a system wherein multiple, mutually-suspicious applications (or "applets" in the Java parlance) would simultaneously inhabit a single address space, running in a single VM. Because the designers didn't want one app to be able to mess with another, they went through great pains to define an intra-VM security model that would disallow things such as one object touching the private fields of another object of a different class.

That said, the Java library ended up having various "escape hatches" out of the security model. One of those is `setAccessible()` on reflection objects, as you note.

Android's model is different: Android uses processes as the security boundary and unit of application isolation, instead of trying to insinuate it *into* the process as was done with traditional JVMs. This renders moot the entirety of the Java security model, *except* in that it helps an application "save it from itself." That is, it's good design to not have an object poke into another object's private parts, and the default Java security model provides just that.

Leaving aside the question of people modifying your code, with Android, as an application author, you control all the code that ends up running inside the process of your app. If you choose to include code that calls `setAccessible()` that's your business. You might be shooting yourself in the foot, but you certainly won't be shooting any other apps' feet, since the Android security model, running as it as at the layer of processes, inherently doesn't let that happen. Likewise, using native code will totally break you out of the Java object model, which allows for the possibility of things going totally higgledy-piggledy in the process but also allows you to express some things in a more productive manner than you could in Java. It's a trade-off, but it's a per-application-developer tradeoff and not one that particularly impacts anything else that's happening on your phone / device.

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but I hope it provided some useful context.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to prevent this kind of access from outside code?

Not really.

> is there a similar mechanism for Android as well?

Even if there is (and I am not aware that such a thing exists), anyone can remove it, by decompiling your code (assuming they do not have your source already), getting rid of the protection, and recompiling the code.

Bear in mind that ProGuard, when used properly, will obfuscate your private classes and methods for your production APK builds. That, plus a lack of documentation, will make it tedious for anyone to gain access to those private classes and methods.

Comment: The idea is not to ensure a 100% protection on first attempt, but 'discourage' illegal use. I know ProGuard would help and anyone can decompile and all that, but I can try to defend my code. That way, I can at least reduce the number of people having the skill and time to exploit all these loopholes.

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal: You are welcome to spend your time however you wish. One would hope that there would be something better you could do with that time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can ever really 100% protect from users using reflection on your project with malicious intent.  You can make it more difficult for users to do it by doing things like obfuscating your code, but it is still possible to reflect on the obfuscated code.

I don't believe SecurityManager can be used for the purpose that you are suggesting, though I could be wrong.